# Programming language to use for a project

Tags: web

Hello i need  a good language and web development frame work that support uploading chunk files via web socket from client to server in an asynchronous mode (i know node.js any other one )?

The current project I am working on is heavily dependent on this particular feature.

Comment: i know programming languages lol im not a  "new beginner"  i need a specific framework on a language  that supports the three features (web sockets,async and chunk uploads). That will make it easier

Answer (score 0):

that's true. Yes,java,python,ruby support too

Answer (score 0):

Some good programming languages that support asynchronous programming are

- Node.js
  Node.js is basically server-side JavaScript, and is very easy to pick up.
- Erlang
  Erlang is a programming language used for building soft, largely scalable, real time  apps.
- Python
  Python is a dynamic, function based programming language that is very easy to learn.